# Calling an EJB interface within a @Singleton

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I'm currently working with Java EE (WildFly 8.0)
I have the following classes:

```
public interface A { 
    public void method(); 
}
```

It's Implementation

```
@Stateless
public class  ABean implements A { 
    public void method() { //do stuff} 
}
```

And a Singleton which has this interface as an EJB

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class Singleton  { 
    @EJB
    public A a; 
}
```

Whenever I call Singleton.a.method() within another EJB in my business logic, it throws an 
InvokationException saying: EJB Invocation failed.

Is there something missing here? I already tried declaring the interface @Local but still the same problem.

Comment: Just realized my singleton won't get initialized, I added @Startup and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the method call inside a method in the singleton?

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class TestSingleton  { 

    @Inject
    public ITest a; 


    public void Run() {
        a.Method();
    }
}
```

This works for me on Wildfly 8.1, while TestSingleton.a.Method() fails with a NullPointer.